# Search Engine for MongoDB ?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, search-engine

i'm using mongodb to store data.
But to search I prefer to use elasticsearch or similar. But i didn't found solution.
Because I read some problems and issues with RIVER .

What's your experience and recommendations ?

Comment: SO does not "recommend" however, I personally replicate to MySQL and use that with Sphinx. SOlr is another good option and MongoDB has an alpha state search tech of its own.

Comment: If you want to use Elasticsearch, then Elasticsearch with an appropriate river is the way to go. If you have concerns or need help figuring out the best solution for your situation, try the Elasticsearch mailing list/group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

I'm using elasticsearch with mongodb. I tried Solr but I didnt have the integration. The two tools are using the lucene so has "approximately" the same query syntax.

There are [some tutorial](http://satishgandham.com/2012/09/a-complete-guide-to-integrating-mongodb-with-elastic-search/), but it didnt work for me. I believe the reason is that the github doesnt allow now to upload and download binary files. So, we can not use the `./plugin` command. To overcome this problem you have to `git clone` the repositories and make the .jar files on your own. To do that you have to use apache maven and make `mvn package` to create the packages.

Add both river and [Mapper Attachments](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments) to elasticsearch. And make sure that you follow the compatible versions according to the [river version table](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb#mongodb-river-plugin-for-elasticsearch).

After that everything will working file.